# need to form SQL join/subQuery on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sybase

There are 3 tables -

tables  ---  columns

**ABC** - abc_id, abc_name, active_flag

**XYZ** - xyz_id, xyz_name, active_flag

**ABC_XYZ** - abc_xyz_id, abc_id, xyz_id, active_flag

id column in each table is PK
I need to form a query which will return output like - for each abc_name there will be multiple xyz_names

like below -

abc_name1 -

```
    xyz_name1
    xyz_name2
    xyz_name3
    xyz_name4
```

abc_name2 -

```
    xyz_name5
    xyz_name6
    xyz_name2
    xyz_name4
```

I am using sybase DB in my project

any help will be appreciated

Comment: What output yu need?

Comment: You should show your existing tables with data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To join all 3 your tables, you can start fro the table ABC_XYZ as shown below-

You can get some more details [HERE](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/introduction-to-sql-joins?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=1455363063&utm_adgroupid=65083631748&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=278443377086&utm_targetid=dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=9074038&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIqdjitIKr6gIViSQrCh1l8wPCEAAYAiAAEgKV0_D_BwE) about SQL JOIN

```
SELECT * 
-- SELEC * will return all records from all tables
-- You can also select specific column from different table usinf table Alias and column name
FROM ABC_XYZ A
INNER JOIN ABC B ON A.abc_id = B.abc_id 
INNER JOIN XYZ C ON A.xyz_id = C.xyz_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mkRabbani - Thats what I wanted.
I just added active flag also -
SELECT * 
FROM ABC_XYZ A
INNER JOIN ABC B ON A.abc_id = B.abc_id 
INNER JOIN XYZ C ON A.xyz_id = C.xyz_id
where B.active = 1 and C.active = 1